# Is it correct to use dectlype to deduce the data type in template's element type?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, templates, decltype

Hello I am asked to simulate the algorithm `std::copy_if` in this example to copy the odd values into s `list` of integers and the even ones also int another list so here is my example:

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
bool is_odd_pred(T x) {
    return x % 2 != 0;
}

template <typename T>
bool is_even_pred(T x) {
    return !(x % 2);
}


template <class T, class U>
void cpy_if(T first, T last, U destIt, bool(*pfnPred)(decltype(*first + 1))) {
    while (first != last) {
        if (pfnPred(*first))
            *destIt++ = *first;
        ++first;
    }
}



int main() {

    std::vector<int> v1{ 10, 27, 57, 77, 81, 24, 16, 23, 28 };

    for (auto i : v1)
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::list<int> li_odd;
    //cpy_if(v1.cbegin(), v1.cend(), li.begin(),
    //  [](decltype(*v1.cbegin() + 1) a) { return (a % 2 != 0);  });

    cpy_if(v1.cbegin(), v1.cend(), std::back_inserter(li_odd), is_odd_pred);


    for (auto i : li_odd)
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::list<int> li_even;

    cpy_if(v1.cbegin(), v1.cend(), std::back_inserter(li_even), is_even_pred);


    for (auto i : li_even)
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program looks to work fine but Is it that correct context to use `decltype` in my `cpy_if` algorithm? Because I only  made the algorithm has two elements types which are considered to be iterators.?  Thank you for any help, tips, suggestion.

Comment: Why `decltype(*first + 1)` and not `decltype(*first)`? Isn't it the same?

Comment: @user31264 The second one is a reference.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa Please don't make significant changes to the question after you received an answer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes. I haven't done.

Comment: @user31264: AFAIK using `decltype` with parenthesized object will yield a reference so to make it just simple data type I make the parenthesized expression `rvalue` that is why I've added `1`: `int x = 0; decltype(x + 1)` yields `int` while `decltype(x)` yields `int&`.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa I was talking about you editing out the  `+ 1`. :) I've edited it back in.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Ok get it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The glaring problem is that `*first + 1` doesn't work for some types.

I assume you've added it to prevent `decltype` from giving you a reference. If so, a more reliable equivalent is:

```
bool(*pfnPred)(std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*first)>>)
```

Starting from C++20, it can be shortened to:

```
bool(*pfnPred)(std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(*first)>)
```

---

Next, using a function pointer imposes unnecessary restrictions on the predicate.

It doesn't let you use stateful lambdas, or functions with slightly different parameter types (such as `bool pred(const int &) {...}`).

Rather than using a function pointer, you can make your function accept arbitrary callable objects. (This is how the standard algorithms work.)

```
template <class T, class U, class F>
void cpy_if(T first, T last, U destIt, F pfnPred) {
    while (first != last) {
        if (pfnPred(*first))
            *destIt++ = *first;
        ++first;
    }
}
```

For extra safety, you can use `pfnPred(std::as_const(*first))` to prevent the predicate from accepting a parameter by a non-const reference and modifying it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really interesting.

Comment: But now I get this error: `Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error C2783 'void cpy_if(T,T,U,F)': could not deduce template argument for 'F' ConsoleApplication1 c:\users\raindrop7\desktop\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp 110`

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa Oh, that's because `is_odd_pred` and `is_even_pred` are templates. Try using `is_odd_pred<int>`, or a lambda: `[](int x){return x % 2 == 1;}`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `decltype(*first)` or `decltype(*first + 1)` it is considered more proper to use

```
typename iterator_traits<T>::value_type
```

Comment: Where to put this?

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa directly in place of your `decltype(...)` construct, not forgetting to precede `iterator_traits` with `std::` and to include `<iterator>` header.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the predicates' type as a template argument and make use of the function template argument deduction. For more inspiration ( and possible implementation tips ) : 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy